# How to display the list of inputed name and time in java?

Tags: java

[image]

kindly help me.. 
I have a code here in the picture..
I want to display the list of name and time using java..
Thanks..

Comment: Add the code in plain text (not an image) as an edit to your question, be a tad more specific and have you tried to format anything at all yet?

Comment: Be sure to use the four-space indent on code (click the `{}` button to apply it)

Comment: @gparyani But don't forget to select the code sample (or output etc.) before clicking `{}`.  ;)  To copy from the Windows command line, 1) right click (produces menu) 2) `Mark` (makes different prompt) 3) Drag or shift+arrow to select the text of interest. 4) `Enter` to copy to clipboard.

Comment: sir kindly make a solution of my problem..

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to store the names in an array, just like you tried to store the times in an array. Right now, you're storing them in the `stry` variable, which is being overwritten every time the loop iterates. Something like this: `p[i]=br.readLine();`

Second, on the part where you read the time, (I assume) you should be using the variable `pt` instead of `p`.

Third, you will need to change the index from `r` to `i` where you read the time. Something like this: `pt[r]` to `pt[i]`.

Fourth, you will need a line to read and store the information for `wt[i]`.

Fifth, you will need to create another loop to output the data:

```
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    System.out.print("\n" + p[i] + "\t\t" + pt[i] + "\t\t" + wt[i]);
}
```

There are other issues with your code, such as poor variable names, and poor use of arrays, but I assume you are a beginner so I will not badger you with those.

Comment: I'm not going to write your homework for you. If you cannot figure out how to do these things, please seek a tutor in Java.